Chinese? Entries in Systemd's Log
I have a vm that is locking up I'd say every other day or so. I went digging through logs to look for clues and my systemd logs found at /var/lib/systemd/catalog/database are mostly in what looks like Chinese. I'm an American who only speaks English. Any idea whats going on. Sample logs:
結果為 @JOB_RESULT@。
Subject: 行程 @EXECUTABLE@ 無法執行
Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

行程 @EXECUTABLE@ 無法執行且失敗。

由該行程所回傳的錯誤碼為 @ERRNO@。
Subject: 一個或更多訊息無法被轉發到 syslog
Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

一個或更多訊息無法被轉發到 syslog 服務
以及並行執行的 journald。這通常代表著
syslog 實作並無未跟上佇列中訊息
的速度。
Subject: 掛載點不為空
Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

目錄 @WHERE@ 被指定為掛載點（在 /etc/fstab 中的
第二欄或是在 systemd 單位檔案中的 Where= 欄位）且其不為空。
這並不會干擾掛載，但在此目錄中已存在的檔案
會變成無法存取的狀態。要檢視這些 over-mounted 的檔案，
請手動掛載下面的檔案系統到次要
位置。
Subject: 虛擬機器或容器已啟動
Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

虛擬機器 @NAME@ 包含它的領導 PID @LEADER@ 現在
已經開始並已經可以使用。
Subject: 虛擬機器或容器已結束
Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS

Are you viewing this file using journalctl - or via some other method?

My /var/lib/systemd/catalog/database has Russian, Chinese, Spanish (and probably other languages). My system language is set to be English and no other language pack is installed. I presume it is intentional and does not indicate any malware, but I have no idea why it has so many languages

@steeldriver I did cat /var/lib/systemd/catalog/database

That file is not a log file. It is a fixed set of templates for messages that systemd can generate. Words like @EXECUTABLE@ would be replaced by an actual filename when the template is used.
